# How to randomly shuffle images into picture boxes in Visual Basic Forms?

Tags: visual-studio

So I have a 6x4 arrangement of picture boxes drawn on my form. My idea is to create a matching game. I want to add images to the picture boxes randomly each time so that they're not in the same position each time someone plays the game. The images will be stored in a file somewhere on my computer. I'm kind of lost at how to approach this. So far I have:

```
Public Class Board
    Dim cards(23) As Image
    Dim random As New Random

    Public Sub shuffle()
        For i = 0 To cards.Length - 1
            cards(i) = i
        Next i
    End Sub

End Class
```

This hasn't really gotten me anywhere. I'm kinda new to using VB for things like this so I'd appreciate any suggestions. Also, the pictures that will be matched aren't exactly the same so I want to add 24 images and not 12 images x 2. Eventually I'll have to figure out the conditions for matching but for now I just want to be able to fill the boxes. And I was wondering if it's worth using OOP or is this not complex enough for that. Thanks in advance.